# XmlSerializer treated as private, although is public

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, access-levels

```
internal XmlSerializer wut = new XmlSerializer();
```

gives me `compiler error cs0122`.
When mousing over `XmlSerialzier` it is listed as a public class.
Any guesses?

I would provide relevant content, but I have no clue where the issue might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object using the parameterless constructor.

But when you look at the class you'll see that [this particular constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ek2t8yy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `protected` which means you can't use it directly.

You have to use one of the other public constructors to create on object of the `XmlSerializer` class.

Comment: There we go! Thank you. I didn't know constructors can have different protection levels than their classes.

Comment: @Mark It can be useful if you have a class with several constructors. You can then extract the common code of all those constructors to a private/protected constructor and use constructor chaining to call it.

Comment: good point. I assumed as much, but thought these constructors just wouldn't be exposed / not shown to me by my IDE.

Comment: @Mark It might show it since the constructor is protected and the class isn't sealed so you *could* inherit from XmlSerializer and call that constructor. But that's just speculation from my end.

Comment: I guess we'll never know, since it works now and I'm happy ;-)

Thanks again.